# Efficient way to query the DB and make API requests

Tags: php, mongodb, api

I need to make approx 25000 thousand requests to an API to fetch data, and the keywords for those requests are stored in MongoDb.

Currently I do this (pseduo code):

```
$documents = $collection->find([ //conditions here ]);

// iterate through each row/document
foreach ($documents as $document) {
  //grab the keyword
  $keyword = $document['keyword'];
  // make an API request
  $AdditionalData = APIRequest($keyword, $arguments);
  // store fetched data in another collection
  $anotherCollection->insert($AdditionalData);
}
```

... but since the requests are in thousands and I have to do this daily so I'm wondering if there's a better and more efficient way to do it?

Would it be faster If I stored the keywords in an array so its a single query to the db and then use it to make API requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not sure if this will help but i would recommend use distinct for all documents. If you have query distinct wont work.

```
//this will filter all results and return only distinct keywords
$docs = $collection->distinct('keyword');
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

For find try to return less amount of data. Only keywords by using projection
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection

For api requests if you can send bunch of keywords and then save results also will increase performance.

Off-course save data still be the same time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh the keywords are already unique, its basically getting a product `document` and then its unique `MPN`.